Как указать адрес памяти на шине I2C для библиотеки EEPROM.h?
Искал функцию для указания адреса EEPROM-памяти в библиотеке EEPROM.h. Существует ли он вообще? Если нет, то какие альтернативы (помимо традиционной отправки байтов на шину с помощью Wire.h) имеются?

В i2c контроллере обычно есть регистр с именем TAR (Target Address Register) или какой-то похожий. Ищите, что-то в этом роде в своей библиотеке

https://alexgyver.ru/lessons/eeprom/

@AlexanderChernin, в данной Вами статье ничего не сказано про указание адреса устройства.

А вот это не оно EEPROM.write(адрес, данные)?

Библиотека EEPROM.h предназначена для работы с памятью EEPROM, встроенной в микроконтроллер.
Для работы с I2C-устройствами используется библиотека Wire.h.
